# Borré mis archivos con `git reset --hard HEAD`

Tags: git, git-commit

Estaba revisando el único commit que había realizado, quería deshacerlo por completo (no borrar mis archivos), busqué en algunos sitios de internet, y vi uno donde ponían `git reset --hard HEAD` así que inocentemente lo hice yo también... ahora todos mis archivos de la carpeta se borraron. 
Lo peor es que ya no figura mi carpeta vacía como un repositorio inicializado.
¿Hay alguna manera de recuperar los archivos o ya no hay esperanza?

Comment: Si al menos conocieras el id del commit anterior, debería. Como tal debe existir dentro del directorio .git del proyecto. Echa un vistazo ahí dentro a ver si consigues encontrar ese id de commit. Si lo encuentras entonces aún hay esperanza...

Comment: Si lo tengo, y cuando entro al proyecto por cmd, me aparece el .git, pero cuando entro por git bash, me dice que no he inicializado el proyecto en git, es decir, como si no hubiese hecho un git init.

Comment: Intenta `git reflog show` y `git reset HEAD@{1}` . El 1 es el numero de la acción dependiendo de lo que sale en el primer comando. [Recover from git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)